# Wordpress pagination con ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

he implementado pagination de wordpress a mi web

```
<?php
  global $wp_query;

  $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

  echo paginate_links( array(
   'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
   'format' => '?paged=%#%',
   'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
   'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ) );
?>
```

Pero resulta que necesito implementarlo con ajax, y no tengo ni idea como, alguien me puede hechar una mano?
Gracias y un saludo

Comment: Tal vez podrías utilizar este [plugin de paginación ajax](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/malinky-ajax-pagination/).

Comment: No, esto no me sirve, por que no quiero usar plugins